# Horrible effect while baking lightmaps in Unity. Shadow doesn't match the model

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image]

Hi!
After baking the light for this model I have the most strange effect. Shadow completely doesn't match the model and it's totally broken. On the right side, as you can see, the setup of light baking is basic. Directional light and emission on the island are the only sources of light. The project is configured for Android devices. Please help, because this drives me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have the answer. I had to turn on Double Sided Global Illumination in shader settings. Now all works fine. Thread resolved.

[image]